# Rails 4 Api returning all user data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have an api that I am building for phones, where I am trying to return the data for only the current user when I do a get request:

Api Controller:

```
**Shows me one specific user -- which is what I want**
respond_with Mibox.where(:user_id  => 19 ).load

**Shows me all user boxes**
respond_with Mibox.all
respond_with Mibox.where(:user_id  => session[:user_id]).load
respond_with Mibox.where(:user_id  => session[:current_user] ).load
```

How can I limit the scope to the current user or current session user id? For some reason it says it can not find current_user, even though Devise is supposed to make it available for all controllers and view. I am using devise with the built in api for rails. I am using the old method of authorization tokens (which I will update once I have this all completed).

respond_with Mibox.where(user: current_user).load

```
Started GET "/api/v1/miboxes.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-21 13:23:08 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::MiboxesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"mibox"=>{}}
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'vNpqxmNcy8oP1V8BYzmF' LIMIT 1
  Mibox Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "miboxes".* FROM "miboxes" WHERE "miboxes"."user" IS NULL
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: miboxes.user: SELECT "miboxes".* FROM "miboxes"  WHERE "miboxes"."user" IS NULL
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: miboxes.user: SELECT "miboxes".* FROM "miboxes"  WHERE "miboxes"."user" IS NULL):
  app/controllers/api/v1/miboxes_controller.rb:52:in `index'
```

respond_with Mibox.where(user_id: current_user.id).load

```
`Started GET "/api/v1/miboxes.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-21 13:19:44 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::MiboxesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"mibox"=>{}}
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'vNpqxmNcy8oP1V8BYzmF' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/api/v1/miboxes_controller.rb:52:in `index'`
```

Here is the mibox schema:

```
create_table "miboxes", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "myboximages"
    t.text     "name"
    t.string   "qrcode"
    t.text     "location"
  end

  add_index "miboxes", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_miboxes_on_user_id_and_created_at"
```

Controller

```
   class Api::V1::MiboxesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :restrict_access
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
  after_filter :cors_access

  respond_to :json

  def cors_access
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end


  rescue_from(ActionController::ParameterMissing) do |parameter_missing_exception|
    error = {}
    error[parameter_missing_exception.param] = ['parameter is required']
    response = { errors: [error] }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: response, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end




  def index
    respond_with Mibox.where(user_id: current_user).load
  end






  def show
    respond_with Mibox.find(params[:id])
    #@mibox = current_user.miboxes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    respond_with Mibox.create(mibox_params)
  end

  def update
    respond_with Mibox.update(params[:id], mibox_params)
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with Mibox.destroy(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def set_mibox
    @mibox = Mibox.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def mibox_params
    #params.require(:mibox).permit!
    params.require(:mibox).permit(:content, :location, :myboximages, :myboximages_cache, :remove_myboximages, :name, :user_id, tag_list: [])
  end


  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      User.exists?(authentication_token: token)
      #User.find_by(params[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers), we can see that the correct helper method is `#current_user`.

ie:

```
respond_with Mibox.where(user: current_user).load
```

or

```
respond_with Mibox.where(user_id: current_user.id).load
```

Of course, this assumes that you've already authenticated the user.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated the question with the output. Unfortunately, I get errors. I've posted the schema to see if that might help.

Comment: The issue is easy to spot: current_user is null. Are you sure you've authorized the user? ie: following the [devise controller structure](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)?

Comment: Ah. When I add in before_filter :authenticate_user!, it asks me to sign in. I sign in grab the auth token and do a get, then it denies me: "error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." I was using an old tutorial that ran off of auth_tokens What would you recommend at this point? I added my controller above.

Comment: If you're using the API outside of a browser, you probably don't have a session being stored. I actually recently wrote a blog post about [API authentication with Devise](http://soryy.com/ruby/api/rails/authentication/2014/03/16/apis-with-devise.html) that you might want to check out.

Comment: Thats kinda what I figured. There does not seem to be a session id to fall back on. I'll def read your post and thanks again!

Comment: If that resolves your question, please select an answer.